# Почему вместо русских символов знаки вопроса после создания pdf файла через PHPEcles?

Tags: php, phpexcel, tcpdf, dompdf

Почему вместо русских символов знаки вопроса после создания pdf файла через PHPExcel?

Сам файл кода utf. При сохранении в excel, то кодировка нормальная, именно при сохранении в PDF такие символы.

Создаю через new PHPExcel(); таблицу с данными, в конце сохраняю данные в файл pdf через класс PHPExcel_Writer_PDF

```
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;

$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/../resources/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Writer/PDF/DomPDF.php';

if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
    $rendererName,
    $rendererLibraryPath
)) {
    die(
      'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
       '<br />' .
       'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
    );
 }


 $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_PDF($xls);
 $objWriter->save(dirname(__FILE__).'/d.pdf');
```

При открытии файла, знаки вопроса вместо русских букв:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать шрифт dejavusans, т.к. он поддерживает кириллицу. Например:

```
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);
```

Где `$pdf` - это экземпляр класса